# Solution using spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have two tables one contains rules and other data on which I have to run rule as below.

[TabA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIof5.png)

[TabB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mOM3.png)

My requirement is to frame queries dynamic queries for rach rule and run it dynamically using spark.

#no of rules are can be more I have given few to understand the problem statement.
#each rule will have different formula
query will look like:

select 'A' as rule_nm,sum(am1) as val from tabB where item1 in('1','2','3') and item2 not in('7','8')

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that table B is registered in the spark session, eg:

```
val dfForTableB = spark.read...
dfForTableB.createOrRegisterTempView("tabB")
```

You can then execute the sql statements you are generating via SparkSQL:

```
val firstDf = spark.sql("select 'A' as rule_nm,sum(am1) as val from tabB where item1 in('1','2','3') and item2 not in('7','8')")
firstDf.write...
```

If you need a single dataframe, assuming you are using scala, you could do the following:

```
rules.tail.foldLeft(applySql(rules.head))((df, rule) => df.unionAll(applySql(rule))))
```

Comment: I have 500 such rules 500 df will be there. Again I need to Union all to compute the final result. Isnt it possible to frame queries dynamic.